# jquery menu plugin similar to superfish

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I just found good looking jquery menu plugin called superfish http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples

But the thing it - is looks like it was updated last time in 2008 and probably no future support...

May be some one may suggest something similar with the same functional but more up to dated?

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason not to use Superfish just because it's a few years old. It's a great plugin and still works with the latest jquery.